# VueJS v-bind:style for background-image: url()

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

According to `VueJS` docs:

> `<div v-bind:style="{ color: activeColor, fontSize: fontSize + 'px' }"></div>`

I've tried several patterns:

```
<div v-bind:style="{ background-image: url(item.img), }"></div>

<div v-bind:style="{ 'background-image': url('item.img'), }"></div>

<div v-bind:style='{ backgroundImage: "url(item.img)", }'></div>
```

But the results are not valid for the HTML `style` attribute.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

After trying other patterns, this is the one that works:

`<div v-bind:style='{ backgroundImage: "url(" + item.img + ")", }'></div>`

Results in:

`<div style='{ background-image: url("/img/path/img.jpg"), }'></div>`

Answer (score 6):

based on @T.Abdullaev's answer,
this one with extra double quote worked for me.

```
v-bind:style='{ backgroundImage: `url("${imgUrl}")` }'
```

Answer (score 4):

Do this. It works also for templates.

```
<div :style='{ backgroundImage: `url(${item.img})` }'></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

For me this seemed to work just fine:

```
 :style="{
      'background-image': 'url(' + require(`../assets/img/${imageName}`) + ')'
  }"
```

Since all my images were in the assets folder, the images could be accessed using the above pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Using a computed property works very well, and is cleaner:

```
computed: {
     imageUrl: function() {
         return 'url('+ this.path + ')';
     }
},
```