# Set background image of div in CSS

Tags: css

I have a webpage written in html and css as a prototype. Now we're implementing this using VueJS.
I want to have a picture as a background in the homepage. The problem is that I try to create a `div` within the template, then style it from the `style` part, but the picture doesn't come up. I tried linking the picture in an `img` tag, and it shows which means that the page is correctly linked through the router, and the url is correct.

here is the code that I think is supposed to work:

```css
.background {
  background-image: url(../assets/img/21.jpg);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<template>
      <div>
        <div class="background"></div>
      </div>
</template>
```

I tried to follow with the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666716/vuejs-v-bindstyle-for-background-image-url) but they made no difference.

am I missing something or what exactly is wrong here?

Comment: It works, but your div's height is 0 so... You can tell there's nothing in it, nor does css specify its height.

Comment: Add a word to your background div and see the bg image. As mentioned above, you have no content in the div so it doesn't visually appear on page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @N.B. said: div's height is missing.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsh5bq30/10/)

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class="background"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/1920x900);
}
```

Remember your div's height can't be 100% as long as your parent div's height is not set.

If you want 100% width and height use
[this](http://jsfiddle.net/tsh5bq30/14/)

HTML:

```
<div class="template">
  <div class="background-parent">
    <div class="background"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.background-parent
{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
.background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/1920x900);
}
```